# How to add CC using java script in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, outlook-2010

```
function SendMail(to,body,sub)
{
    var theApp  ;  
    var theMailItem ;  
    var subject = sub;
    var msg = body;


    var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application")
    var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(0);
    theMailItem.to = to;
    theMailItem.Subject = (subject);
    theMailItem.Body = (msg);
    theMailItem.send();  

}
```

I'm using above code to send `mails` from the client machine, but in this i would like to add `cc` could anyone kindly help me on this or if there is any other methods to send `mails` from client side help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The mail item has a `CC` property. Just set it before send.

```
theMailItem.CC = "carbon copy recipient goes here";
```

Also, have in mind that the property names are case sensitive. So change `to` to `To` and `send` to `Send`

Answer (score 0):

```
var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
        var objNS = theApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
        var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(0);
        theMailItem.cc = cc;
        theMailItem.to = to;
        theMailItem.Subject = (subject);
        theMailItem.Body = (msg);
        theMailItem.send();
```

I have added this line, var objNS = theApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI'); You should now be able to find the cc attribute.